Docker fails with exec error when calling script from Dockerfile, works when calling directly
Summary: The exec format error is a bit misleading in this case. Here it was just a script typo causing the error. Normally, it indicates building and running on different platforms.
I'm trying to build a Splunk forwarder in a Docker container.
Just for background, the Splunk forwarder container is going to run alongside a Snort 3 Docker container and share a Docker volume on /var/log/snort to get the Snort logs. Then the forwarder output will be sent to the Splunk receiver in another container, which I know very little about at this point, haven't gotten there yet. And to boot, this all runs in a Ubuntu 24.04 VM. This is for a cybersecurity class project, not a production setup!
I have this Dockerfile that has an ENTRYPOINT that calls a startupSplunk.sh script I have ADDed to the container.
When I build and run the container, I use these commands:
docker build -t firewallsplunk .
docker run -it --mount 'type=volume,source=snortlogs,dst=/var/log/snort' firewallsplunk
I get this error:
exec /tmp/startupSplunk.sh: exec format error
So, assuming my shell script isn't throwing the exec format error, I look at what my script does, it calls the /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk executable. So, it must be that I downloaded the wrong package or something? Remember I installed splunk with dpkg -i so I'd think that would catch a wrong platform error.
But when I startup the container with a CMD ["bash"] in the Dockerfile and poke around, I can directly run the /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk executable without any exec format errors.
root@CS6035-24:/home/machine/firewallProject/firewallSplunk# ./run.sh 
splunkfwd@2c6d93f04e2e:/$ /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk -help     
Warning: Attempting to revert the SPLUNK_HOME ownership
Warning: Executing "chown -R splunkfwd:splunkfwd /opt/splunkforwarder"
SPLUNK GENERAL TERMS

Last Updated: August 12, 2021
...

To restate the question, why am I getting the exec format error when I try to run my script through an ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile, but when I run the same commands directly in the container in bash, it works fine? I thought for a second maybe it was a bash vs sh thing, but I launch my container with sh instead of bash and can still run the command without the annoying exec format error.
Thanks for any help.

I did see this post but I'm not running on a Mac, I'm in an Ubuntu 24.04 VM running on a Windows 11 host.

Thanks! At the same time, I'm having too much fun learning how to do it on my own, I'll pull their image from Dockerhub as a last resort. And I really think my question is a Docker question, not really a Splunk question. Thanks again.

I had asked this a couple days ago https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/781772/ubuntu-22-docker-container-cant-set-promiscuous-mode-in-a-dockerfile-but-can-o where I just had the wrong mental model about Docker, I suspect it's the same thing here. What throws me is that it's an exec format error, can't understand where that's coming from.

Your startupSplunk.sh file should start with #!/bin/bash instead of #/bin/bash.

arrrrrggggghhhh. That was it.
I don't know if it's worth writing that up as an answer, now I'm not sure my question is really worth leaving here, I might delete it.
UPDATE: I thought about it, it would be valuable for Google to show this for people searching this error, so if you answer, I'll accept @larsks. Otherwise I'll answer it myself tomorrow. THANKS for scrutinizing my files, much appreciated!

Bottom line, this had nothing to do with what exec format error is normally trying to express. If you got here from Google, first make sure you're not actually trying to build on one platform and run on another.
In my case as @larsks pointed out, my ENTRYPOINT script had a typo.

Your startupSplunk.sh file should start with #!/bin/bash instead of
#/bin/bash

I'm posting this answer, because when I searched Google for Docker exec format error, everything pointed to the obvious platform issue, nothing suggested that this type of misconfiguration could be the culprit.
